# NPM Import linked packages as sub modules

Tags: npm, npm-link

I'm working on a project which has a few different modules, for example:

```
/project
    /app
    /website
    /api
    /common
        /dist (gets generated from the ts build)
        /types (gets generated from the ts build)
        /src
            /index.ts
            /security.ts
            /accounting.ts
```

The common directory contains common functions/calculations etc. that I might need to access between the various other projects that way I don't need to duplicate code.

I am aware of npm link and have tried that, and works okay, but what I want is more fine grained imports, for example:

```
import accounting from 'common/accounting';
import security from 'common/security';
```

When I try this, I get the following error:
`Cannot find module 'common/accounting' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

rather than doing these:

```
import common from 'common';
const accounting = common.accounting;
const security = common.security;
```

or this:

```
import accounting from 'common/dist/accounting';
import securityfrom 'common/dist/security';
```

(The above both work)

This is a list of things I have tried for `package.json` for the common folder (there's probably more but I can't remember at the moment):

**1**

```
{
    "name": "common",
    "main": "dist",
    "types": "types",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./dist/index.js",
        "./accounting": "./dist/accounting.js",
        "./security": "./dist/security.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {...},
    "scripts": {...}
}
```

**2**

```
{
    "name": "common",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "types/index.d.ts",
    "dependencies": {...},
    "scripts": {...}
}
```

**3**

```
{
    "name": "common",
    "main": "dist",
    "types": "types/index.d.ts",
    "dependencies": {...},
    "scripts": {...}
}
```

**4 (tsconfig.json)**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "./types",'.d.ts' files
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "typeRoots": ["./types"],
        "paths": {
      "common/*": ["../common/dist/*"]
    }
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*" // source files to include in the compilation
    ]
}
```

Information:

- node: v18.14.2
- npm: v8.19.4
- IDE: vscode v1.80.0
- projects are NextJS except for API which is running Yoga server

**EDIT:** so the code appears to still work, BUT the IDE and typescript are saying it's an error